# Laravel Broadcast in not working with Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-websockets

I am using Pusher in my Web Application. My backend is built with Laravel & Frontend is built with Angular 10. Everything works perfectly in my local machine. But in the server it is not working. Laravel Event is not getting broadcasted.

This is my Broadcasting Event

```
class DrawOptionsChanged implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $options;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($options)
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('draw_options');
    }
}
```

**Calling this with the following code:**

```
event(new DrawOptionsChanged($data));
```

Everything workes perfectly in my local machine. But in the server, both client and laravel-webSockets url is getting connected but events are not received in any of them.

in broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => false,
                'encrypted' => false,
//                'host' => '162.214.125.121',
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
```

I have noticed, events are getting broadcasted by the websocket url and client is also receiving that... But from codes they are not getting broadcasted... Everything works perfectly in local machine...

http://api.etakweet.com/laravel-websockets

**Client Connection Codes**

```
this.pusher = new Pusher(environment.pusher.key, {
      cluster: environment.pusher.cluster,
      wsHost: '162.214.125.121',
      // wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
      wsPort: 6001,
      encrypted: false,
      forceTLS: false,
    });
    this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe('draw_options');
    Pusher.log = (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
    };
```

**Client Binding Codes**

```
this.pusherService.channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
          console.log('successfully subscribed!');
        });
        this.pusherService.channel.bind('App\\Events\\DrawOptionsChanged', res => {
          const data = res.options
          this.major = data.major
          this.degree = data.degree
          this.gender = data.gender
          if (data.generate == 1) {
            this.getResult()
          }
        });
```

[image: pusher connect]

**Broadcasting Code:**

```
public function optionChanged(Request $request)
    {
        $major = $request->input('major');
        $degree = $request->input('degree');
        $gender = $request->input('gender');
        $draw = $request->input('draw');
        $generate = $request->input('generate');
        $data = [
            'major' => $major,
            'draw' => $draw,
            'gender' => $gender,
            'degree' => $degree,
            'generate' => $generate,
        ];

        $drawData = Draw::where('id', $draw)->first();
        $drawData->current_gender = $gender;
        $drawData->current_qualification_type = $degree;
        $drawData->current_major = $major;
        $drawData->save();

        try {
            event(new DrawOptionsChanged($data));
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $exception->getMessage();
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'success'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: can u put your client listen code .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul Added the client codes in the question...

Comment: try laravel `echo` may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

try this laravel echo https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-echo

```js
Echo.channel("draw_options")
            .listen("DrawOptionsChanged ",res  => {
                         const data = res.options
                        this.major = data.major
                        this.degree = data.degree
                        this.gender = data.gender
                        if (data.generate == 1) {
                            this.getResult()
                        }
                    }
                );
```

Comment: My client is not inside Laravel Project. Its a separate angular 10 project.

Comment: `laravel-echo` is javascript library u can use anywhere as long backed is laravel

Comment: but from the logs what i found is event is not getting broadcasted. Like if a event is pushed in local machine, i get a log in console... But in server i saw no log message when event is broadcasted.. so that means the issue is from backend

Comment: exactly... It triggers in local machine... But in server it is not... Very strange

Comment: event(new DrawOptionsChanged($data));

Comment: By any route.?    your r using

Comment: calling an api.. doing some db queries and returning $data in both response and broadcast.... Getting the json response but broadcasat is not working